# How to use the curl command in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, curl, jenkins

Am using the `curl` command in PowerShell to post the comment in bit-bucket pull request page through a Jenkins job. I used the below PowerShell command to execute the `curl` command, but am getting the error mentioned below. Could anyone please help me on this to get it worked?

```
$CurlArgument="-u xxx@gmail.com:yyyy -X POST https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments --data content=success"
$CURLEXE='C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe'
& $CURLEXE $CurlArgument
```

Error Details:

```
curl.exe : curl: no URL specified!
At line:3 char:1
+ & $CURLEXE $CurlArgument
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (curl: no URL specified!:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: Sorry, don't have any experience with curl but why don't you use the built-in PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` cdmlet?

Comment: @MartinBrandl, Am not aware of that, i will check about it and let you know.

Answer (score 28):

Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0).

```
$CurlArgument = '-u', 'xxx@gmail.com:yyyy',
                '-X', 'POST',
                'https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments',
                '--data', 'content=success'
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe'
& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

Comment: Am getting the below error.  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (  % Total    % ...  Time  Current:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: That's `curl` status output. Add the parameter `-s` to suppress it.

Comment: $CurlArgument = '-s', '-u', 'xxx@gmail.com:yyyy',
                '-X', 'POST',
                'https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments',
                '--data', 'content=success'

Comment: much easier than trying to use `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell when it comes to using `content-type: multipart/form-data` :) Thanks

Answer (score 16):

In Powershell 3.0 and above there is both a Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod.  Curl is actually an alias of Invoke-WebRequest in PoSH.  I think using native Powershell would be much more appropriate than curl, but it's up to you :).

Invoke-WebRequest MSDN docs are here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Invoke-RestMethod MSDN docs are here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Unfortunately Invoke_WebRequest is not even close to curl on the list of what you can do with curl. Simple `--verbose` flag is not available to see the details information about TLS connection, RAW http request and response. Am I missing something?

Comment: very useful, thank you! sometimes we get used-to of doing things in a particular way and forget to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 14):

Or another option you could just call curl.exe using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0TransactionID=%22%3Cid_string%3E%22) as follows.

```
> curl.exe '-u', 'xxx@gmail.com:yyyy',
 '-X', 'POST',
 'https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments',                
 '--data', 'content=success'
```

To know where is curl.exe using this command `Get-Command curl.exe`

Other option is to delete aliases curl command with `Invoke-WebRequest`

To see and delete aliaes in PowerShell

```
>Get-Aliases
>Remove-Item alias:curl
```

Then just runing command without '.exe'

```
> curl '-u', 'xxx@gmail.com:yyyy',
 '-X', 'POST',
 'https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments',                
 '--data', 'content=success'
```

I hope this would helps.

Answer (score 8):

PowerShell now supports default aliases, if you type `help curl`
You will get below output

```
NAME
    Invoke-WebRequest

SYNTAX
    Invoke-WebRequest [-Uri] <uri> [-UseBasicParsing] [-WebSession <WebRequestSession>] [-SessionVariable <string>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseDefaultCredentials] [-CertificateThumbprint <string>] [-Certificate
    <X509Certificate>] [-UserAgent <string>] [-DisableKeepAlive] [-TimeoutSec <int>] [-Headers <IDictionary>] [-MaximumRedirection <int>] [-Method {Default | Get | Head | Post | Put | Delete | Trace | Options | Merge | Patch}] [-Proxy
    <uri>] [-ProxyCredential <pscredential>] [-ProxyUseDefaultCredentials] [-Body <Object>] [-ContentType <string>] [-TransferEncoding {chunked | compress | deflate | gzip | identity}] [-InFile <string>] [-OutFile <string>] [-PassThru]
     [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    iwr
    wget
    curl


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Online" or
           go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035.
```

So to download a file you can type

```
curl -Uri "https://www.example.com/myfile.txt" -OutFile myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you!  There were other answers above that pointed to Invoke-WebRequest, but this one showed how it was an alias and gave a concise example. Very helpful answer for the simplest use case where I don't need to be syntatically equivalent with curl.

Comment: Please note that `curl` was removed as an alias in PowerShell Core.

Comment: How can I use above command to download a file using username/password credentials? the `-Credentials 'username:password'` takes `username:password` as just the username, and prompts for a password.

Comment: you can use `-Headers "Basic <base64>"

Answer (score 5):

Instead of curl you can use this command:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use the git-bash commandline tool instead of windows powershell. :)