# Automating SQL Server Express Installation

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to automate the installation of SQL Server Express 2012 using PowerShell, as shown in the following script:

```cs
$Password = "MyP@ssw0rd"
$instanceName = "SQLEXPRESS"
$InstanceId = "SQLEXPRESS"
$User = "sqlsvr12ex"
$SQLAdmins = "VLILEN014120VM\Administrator"
$securestring = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cmd  = @"
"C:\SQLK\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=install  /FEATURES=SQLENGINE
/INSTANCENAME=$($instanceName) /INSTANCEID=$($InstanceId) /SQLSVCACCOUNT="$($User)" /SQLSVCPASSW0RD=""$($securestring)"
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="$($SQLAdmins)" /INDICATEPROGRESS
"@
Write-Host "Installing"
Write-Host $cmd
& cmd.exe /c $cmd
```

However, I failed to install it and got the following error message:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068709375
  Exit facility code:            1202
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  The object state property 'this.InstanceId' is null/empty.
  Start time:                    2017-07-04 16:48:41
  End time:                      2017-07-04 16:49:23
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x7D924E88%400xF762992B%401202%401&EvtType=0x7D924E88%400xF762992B%401202%401

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  VLILEN014120VM
  Machine processor count:       16
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         c:\6edee20eca4fd86987c7534278c4ca\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   true
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170704_164747\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170704_164747\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInvalidOperationException
    Message: 
        The object state property 'this.InstanceId' is null/empty.
    HResult : 0x84b20001
        FacilityCode : 1202 (4b2)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data: 
      ChainerInvalidOperationExceptionData = this.InstanceId
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.InstanceIdPrivateConfigObject.ValidateSettings()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.ValidateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ValidateFeatureSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)
```

So why is that? Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure that the 'SQLSVCPASSW0RD' parameter not require plain text? as you provide a SecureString... ? Also, is it a clean install or you are overwriting existing installation?

Comment: @Avshalom I ran both the plaint text and SecureString and they gave the same error message. It's a clean install.

Comment: Should there be a single quote mark here? `/SQLSVCPASSW0RD=""` <--

Comment: if you are running it without variable expansion, the command is working?

Comment: The error message says that your instance ID is undefined. Why is your commandline wrapped and in a multiline string? Unwrap it, or (better yet) define the commandline arguments as an array and [splat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40105646/1630171) it.

Comment: @MarkWragg Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, that's not the issue.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks. I'll have a try.

Comment: Noticing a zero instead of "O" in /SQLSVCPASSW0RD