# Unable to execute command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-office

Trying to execute the following:

```
function Repair-Office-Apps {
    $OfficeRepair = "/repair ProPlus /config \\server\path$\Custom\MS_Repair\SilentRepairConfig.xml"
    $Office2013   = "\\server\packagepath$\MsOffice2013\setup.exe"
    $Office2016   = "\\server\packagepath$\MsOffice2016\setup.exe"

    # Detect Office Version and repair
    $applist = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
        $_.Name -like "*Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010*" -or
        $_.Name -like "*Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013*" -or
        $_.Name -like "*Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016*"
    }

    if ($applist) {
        foreach ($app in $applist) {
            $AppName = $($app.name)
            Write-Host "$AppName has been detected for repair"
            if ($AppName -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010") {
                Set-Location "C:\Temp\MS_remove"
                Write-Host "Unable to repair Microsoft Office 2010. please manually repair or use the Office reinstall job"
            } else {
                if ($AppName -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013") {
                    Write-Host "Repairing Microsoft office 2013."
                    &  $Office2013 -ArgumentList $OfficeRepair
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Repairing Microsoft office 2016."
                    & $Office2016 -ArgumentList $OfficeRepair
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "No application(s) detected for uninstall"
    }
}

. Repair-Office-Apps
```

The detection of the product works fine, as I use this for uninstalls elsewhere. The help window for the setup executable appears when you run the PowerShell Script, I am unsure on what I am doing wrong when passing the command line arguments. Ideally I would like to pass this command through as a job and query the job results but I thought it best trying to get the basic command built first.

Comment: `&` is shorthand for `Invoke-Expression` (not `Invoke-Command`) and it doesn't have an `-ArgumentList` switch. Try just removing `-ArgumentList` to pass the arguments directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the response. I have tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `&` is PowerShell's [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators). It has nothing to do with the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet.

Comment: I stand corrected. One of those things I "remember reading somewhere".

Comment: @VKrishan [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40105646/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you, worked perfectly.

Comment: `&` != `Invoke-Expression`.