# Getting error when calling flask Restful api in python

Tags: python, flask

Hello there I am beginner in python and I am getting this error when calling api on my local machine 'localhost'

```
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Resource,Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'Hello, World War 3'

class Todo(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self,todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] : request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld,'/')
api.add_resource(Todo,'/<string:todoId>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and Here is the error I am getting while calling this api

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting
value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Its a pretty small code and yet I am unable to catch the real issue.
I am doing as it is on the official site of flask:
[Flask Site](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/quickstart.html)

I have seen other posts on the same issue but they are of high level which I am unable to understand. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I'm not sure how that error relates to your question but it doesn't look like a Flask issue

Comment: What do you think happens the first time you do `http://localhost:5000/1`?

Comment: your `HelloWorld` resource is not returning a JSON object. You are instead returning a `str` type. It should instead be `return {'hello': 'Hello, World War 3'}`

Comment: I did as you said in curl but it returns error 500

Comment: @Tushortz  I corrected it but the issue is still there

Comment: @faizanshafiq update your change in the question

Comment: it may be with your `todoId`. why don't you make it consistent across and use `todo_id` instead of `todoId`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code which are as follows:

- Instead of keeping Todo list empty, add something and test like: `todos = {'1': "Say hello"}`
- The API endpoint for todo is having `todoId` as a string object but in the get and put method you have `todo_id` as a parameter. Both should be same.
- Instead of returning a single string it's better to return a JSON object. Like in your code replace `'Hello, World War 3'` by something like `{'msg': 'Hello, World War 3'}`

**NOTE:** The last one is just for your information to keep all returns standard, and not an issue really.

Use following code for testing, and compare with your code in question. You will get an idea.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {'1': "Say hello"}

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'msg': 'Hello, World War 3'}

class Todo(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self,todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] : request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld,'/')
api.add_resource(Todo,'/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I do get the result when I call

Comment: @faizanshafiq so I solved your issue or still persists? Your comment does not indicate anything related to the solution I gave...

Comment: I did as you said but the error persisted. It seems like the api issue to me

Comment: I am working on another project right now. I will get back soon

Comment: When I write this `curl http://localhost:5000/todo1 -d "data=Remember the milk" -X PUT` I get this error `Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter
cannot be found that accepts argument
'data=Remember the milk'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost:5000/todo1 -d
"data=Remember the milk" -X PUT
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (
   :) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingExce
  ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParamete
   rNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
  keWebRequestCommand`

Comment: @faizanshafiq you are using Microsoft PowerShell to execute curl request, and curl is an alias for PowerShell - Invoke-WebRequest, hence the error... refer this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48495916/512100