# How to fix curl syntax error in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, curl, ftp, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to use `curl` in Windows Powershell to download a file from an SFTP/FTPS site, I have tried to follow the examples in [How to use curl on Windows](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-use-curl-on-windows/), which seem to indicate that I can download from an SFTP/FTPS site. I do the following:

```
PS C:\temp> curl -User 'username:password' -Uri 'ftp://ftp.company.com/devops/path/somefile.txt' -OutFile somefile.txt
```

But I get the following error

```
curl : The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -User 'username:password' -Uri 'ftp://ftp.company.com/devops ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.FtpWebRequest:FtpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], W
   ebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestComma
   nd
```

I've also tried ideas in other Stackoverflow posts, e.g., [How to use the curl command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105458/how-to-use-the-curl-command-in-powershell), to no avail. What is my syntax error?

Comment: Curl in Powershell isn't curl.exe: it's an alias for Invoke-webrequest. You'd either have to download curl for Windows or read up on the documentation on how to use Invoke-webrequest.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, this is a distinction in Windows PowerShell. PowerShell Core no longer has the built-in alias to `Invoke-WebRequest`. That said Windows 10+ does have a MS build of curl in System32. So simply add `.exe` e.g. `curl -> curl.exe`.

Comment: In the terms of PowerShell syntax, it really isn't incorrect. As you've noted, you get a `530` error indicating a wrong credential and not necessarily a syntax error.

Comment: @bluuf I did install `curl` via `chocolatey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- In *Windows PowerShell* (but no longer in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*) `curl` is  built-in alias of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest), whose syntax is very different from that of `curl.exe`.

  - To reliably invoke the latter on Windows, invoke it *with `.exe`* (`curl.exe ...`)
  - `curl.exe` ships with Windows since Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019.
- Your attempt ended up calling `Invoke-WebRequest`, as evidenced by the error message you saw.

  - While your call *technically* fulfills the *syntax* requirements of `Invoke-WebRequest`, it cannot work as intended:

    - `-User`, thanks to PowerShell's "elastic syntax", prefix-matched the `-UserAgent` parameter, which is not your intent.
    - Since no credentials were actually passed (which would require the `-Credential` parameter), you received the error you saw.

---

Therefore, you have two options:

- Stick with [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and use its parameters properly.

  - However, given that FTP support has been removed from `Invoke-WebRequest` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), perhaps using `curl.exe` is better (see next point).
- Switch to [`curl.exe`](https://curl.se/docs) and use *its* parameters properly; e.g.:

  ```
  curl.exe -u 'username:password' ftp://ftp.company.com/devops/path/somefile.txt -o somefile.txt
  ```

Comment: Thanks you! This worked form me. I just had to add the `--ftp-ssl-reqd` option for our SFTP site.