# curl command not working on windows powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, home-assistant

I'm very new to this sort of stuff so please be patient. This is my problem: I'm trying to run a script on my digital loggers webpage on windows powershell using curl but I keep getting errors, as such.

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value
"http://admin:MyPassword@MyIp:MyPort/script?run001=run" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname
could not be parsed."
At line:1 char:6

- curl http://admin:MyPassword@MyIp:MyPort/script?run001=run
- ```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
    I'm more than happy to provide whatever information that is necessary

When i run http://admin:MyPassword@MyIp:MyPort/script?run001=run on chrome it runs the script but i cant get it to work on powershell. The whole purpose of this is so I can have control of my outlets on Home Assistant.

Home assistant does not find any devices for digital loggers on the network so i thought i could just run a script to turn on/off the outlet using curl but I'm struggling

Comment: Have you tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105458/how-to-use-the-curl-command-in-powershell)?

Comment: Question: are you passing `MyPort` literally?

Comment: @sirtao i have replaced MyPort with the actual port number if that's what you are asking

Comment: @codeR i did try those but i might have not fully understood that's why i decided to reach out and ask this question

Comment: Note that in PowereShell, ```curl``` is an alias for the built-in ```Invoke-WebRequest``` cmdlet. If you want to call the stand-alone ```curl``` executable you’ll need to use ```curl.exe``` to disambiguate it.

Comment: @FormalHitman yes, sorry I was not clear in the question. So you are actually using hardcoded values for the varioys `My` elements in your example, is this correct?

Comment: Consider using markdown blocks `~~~` in your question to increase code readability...